# TextBox with TextMode="MultiLine" jumps to end when mouse clicked

Tags: asp.net, webforms, textbox

I have a textbox on webform project. But when I have long text, and focus with click of mouse always jump to the end of the text. How i can stop this jumper?

```
<div class="divInput_2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtObs" runat="server" Width="400" Height="40" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="5000" style="vertical-align:top"   />
            </div>
```

my html when run app:

```
<textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$UC_LstAns$UCAn$txtObs" id="MainContent_UC_ListAns_UCAn_txtObs" style="width: 400px; height: 40px; vertical-align: top;" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: What would you prefer it to do instead? You should be able to hook into the onfocus event to call some function or change it's behavior.

Comment: Can you please share textarea tag which is generated from this from source of html? So that we can figure out something by looking at it.